# Shortcut for toggling wireless network

Tags: windows-7, script, wireless-networking, autohotkey

Right now, when toggling the wireless network, I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. Then the Windows Mobility Center appears. I click Turn Wireless On/Off like in screen shot.

[image]

I scoured the Internet to find an AutoHotkey script for toggling the wireless network, but my efforts were vain. I want <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to be the shortcut. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How about this [ahk thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/36327-disable-wlan-if-lan-cable-is-plugged-in/) and also [wirelessautoswitch](http://www.wirelessautoswitch.com/) which suggested by a user their. But I think its not completely free.

Comment: Those two are related to LAN. The script I want shouldn't be related to LAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about ....

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#z::
Run %windir%\system32\mblctr.exe /open
WinWait, Windows Mobility Center
Sleep, 300
Send, !t
Sleep, 1000
WinClose, A
Return
```

Alternatively you can look here..
http://wlanbook.com/enable-disable-wireless-card-command-line/